# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'LoadChildrenCallback

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I am using `Angular 13` and created a `myapp.mainrouting.js` file and trying to declare `loadChildren` as below:

```
import {CustomerAppHomeComponent} from "../Home/CustomerApp.HomeComponent";
import {Routes} from "@angular/router";    

export const MainRoutes: Routes  = [
  { path: 'Home', component: CustomerAppHomeComponent },
  { path: 'Supplier', loadChildren: '../Supplier/CustomerApp.SupplierModule#CustomerAppSupplierModule' },
  { path: '', component: CustomerAppHomeComponent },
]
```

However, I am getting below error:

```
error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'LoadChildrenCallback | undefined'.

8   { path: 'Supplier', loadChildren: '../Supplier/CustomerApp.SupplierModule#CustomerAppSupplierModule' },
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@angular/router/router.d.ts:1998:5
    1998     loadChildren?: LoadChildren;
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'loadChildren' which is declared here on type 'Route'
```

Comment: Which angular version you are using?, `loadChildren` expects a method now in latest version, [See here](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#lazy-loading-basics)

Comment: I am using `Angular 13`

Comment: Then you should assign module to `loadChildren` as method using `import` function as shown [here](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#lazy-loading-basics)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

For dynamic imports you'll need to update this

```
{ path: 'Supplier', loadChildren: '../Supplier/CustomerApp.SupplierModule#CustomerAppSupplierModule' },
```

To this:

```
{ 
   path: 'Supplier',
   loadChildren: () => import('../Supplier/CustomerApp.SupplierModule').then(x => x.CustomerAppSupplierModule)
},
```

Also double check that in your tsconfig.json you have this line `"module": "esnext"`

```
{
...
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "module": "esnext"
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure in tsconfig.app.json file does not contain module attritube

Answer (score 5):

You are having this issue because of a deprecated style of importing child modules due to angular's new adoption.

Change to this format

```js
{ path: 'Supplier', 
  loadChildren: () => import('../Supplier/SupplierModule.module').then(m => m.SupplierModule },
  
  // *supplier/...*is supposed to be your file name and the *m... us supposed to be your module name
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Also, please note that your tsconfig.json file might need rework, the module key, change its value to "esnext". It is to support the dynamic module loading that is now in use

Answer (score 3):

For Angular 13 below syntax will work. like using promise. loadChildren return promise.

```
{
    path : 'product',
    loadChildren: () => import("./product/product.module").then(module => module.ProductModule)
  },
```